# Injecting Views blocks into another View template

Tags: views

I have a View containing the latest news in a very standard way (ie: one below the other)... I would like to inject, at certain points, other blocks containing other views (ie: latest news with a certain tag), like in this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3c9Dw.jpg

An easy but impractical approach would be to create different views: one for the latest 2, then one for another 3 news with an offset of 2, etc...

But is there some magic that the new D8 theme layer can do to make this more practical?

Comment: There is no additional functionality in D8 Views that makes this version specific.

Comment: ok, tag "8" removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a new View field in modules/yourmodule/lib/Drupal/yourmodule/Plugin/views/Field and "attach" it via hook_views_data_alter() or hook_views_data(). This field would returns a hardcoded view or dynamic, depends on your needs. Another way would be to use Views templates.

Comment: It would be great if you could expand the views template answer a bit. ... Show how to use a preprocess function for the new variable and how you could expand the template.

Comment: i will study the hook_views_data_alter more carefully then as i've never used it... i do use views templates though, but i can't understand how to use them to achieve what i need... maybe i can define a block region in a views template?

Comment: See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8